# Views Filters and logical operator

Tags: 7, views

In my View (using v 3.11), I have a grouped filter exposed. It should show one label for values containing one string OR another, for example:

```
label -> fruit
operator -> contains
value -> apple OR pears
```

I don't want to make two equal labels. It's possible to do that?

Comment: What label are trying change? The view field? The exposed filter field?

Comment: You make the one label apples and the other one pears then they are not equal

Comment: @shawn the exposed filter **drop down** list label

Comment: @reynolds the label of the drop down list MUST be fruit, chosing fruit should show all query results with apple OR pears inside

Comment: for better understanding: from "filter criteris" add new exposed grouped filter with widget type select, at the bottom you have a table with label, operator and value, this creates a dropdown filter list with a string to choose for each label. The filter works for each label one value, but i want for eache label one OR another value. I hope this explains better ;)